# Getting The Colors of the Product from the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I couldn't figure it out to strip the color of the products below. If you help me to do that I appriciate it. I was working on a pandas data frame. Here is the product column and I want to strip and build new column just from the colors. This column is just an example from my data set. There are different types of products with different colors.

| ------------Product--------------- |
| --- |
| youth room (160x220 cm, Dark Grey) |
| Fur Rugs in White - 55x80 cm |

My expected outcome can be like this. Thanks for your support.

| ------------Product--------------- | -------- Color ------ |
| --- | --- |
| youth room (160x220 cm, Dark Grey) | Dark Grey |
| Fur Rugs in White - 55x80 cm | White |

Comment: You need to have a dataset containing the list of colors, as nothing in the product description lets you extract it otherwise.

Comment: do you need colors only?

Comment: as @nonlinear said you need at least a set of expected colors.

Comment: https://github.com/codebrainz/color-names/blob/master/output/colors.csv

Comment: @mr.xed I am still searching that but I need first strip the color name I think ?

Comment: I apologies, I really am not in the coding mode at the moment, I will vote you up. but I think you can loop through the dataframe you have and check for the colors given by what @Bushmaster from a different dataframe with `df[df[columnname].str.contains(colorColumn)]` something like this, but not exactly. I will vote you up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will surely need a list (or any other collection) of the expected colors. Something like this:

```
colors = ["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Dark Grey", "White", "Black"]
```

When you have this defined, the filtering is pretty straightforward.
Here you can find a code example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
example_data = {'Product': ['youth room (160x220 cm, Dark Grey)', 
                            'Fur Rugs in White - 55x80 cm',
                            'Red Modern Chaiselong (120x120 cm)', 
                            'Classic 100x20 cm Armchair Green']}

# Create df with sample data
example_df = pd.DataFrame(example_data)

# List comprehension to find the expected colors in the "Product" column values
example_df['Color'] = example_df['Product'].apply(lambda row: "".join([color for color in expected_colors if color in row]))
```

Which will give us the following output dataframe:

[image]

Comment: `apply` should be avoided when possible. better to use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) here: `df['Color'] = df['Product'].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(colors) + ')')`